# VB 2010 Как передать индекс в событие динамического элемента?

Tags: vb.net

Создан массив элементов и событие `Click`.

Как в событие передать индекс элемента?

```
//Создание элементов
For i = 0 To 5
            PictSet(i) = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
            ... 
                 (свойства объектов)
            ...
            //привязываем событие
            AddHandler PictSet(i).Click, AddressOf PictSet_Click
            //размещаем на  форме
            Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(PictSet(i))
Next i

       // событие
    Private Sub PictSet_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
        //MsgBox("Нажат " & i)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У родительского класс `Control`, от которого унаследованы все WinForms контролы, есть свойство `Tag` типа `object`. Вы можете передавать через него любые данные относящиеся к объекту.

```
//Создание элементов
For i = 0 To 5
    PictSet(i) = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
    PictSet(i).Tag = i
//...

// событие
Private Sub PictSet_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    MsgBox("Нажат " & DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Tag)
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Пытался реализовать это через tag, но не знал как его прочитать в данной ситуации